# Code not working properly datareader from database in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Hi I got an InvalidCastException saying that "Specified cast is not valid". I don't know where is the problem. Does my code has an error? Wordlist column is text field.

This is my code:

```
 public static void Load_Processing_Words()
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\USDB\USDB.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            string query = "Select Wordlist from Words";
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            //while (str != null)
            {
                string str = reader.GetString(0);
                char[] chArray;
                string[] strArray;
                string str2;
                if (str.Contains("Postfix_Exception"))
                {
                    str = reader.GetString(0);
                    chArray = new char[] { '\t', '\n', '\r' };
                    while (!str.Contains("Prefix_Exception"))
                    {
                        strArray = str.Split(chArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        if (strArray.Length != 0)
                        {
                            str2 = strArray[0];
                            if (!Postfix_Exception.Contains(str2))
                            {
                                Postfix_Exception.Add(str2, 1);
                            }
                        }
                        str = reader.GetString(0);
                    }
                }
              }
                con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Define "not working"

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you're not using the reader properly. [`DbDataReader.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a *Boolean* value indicating whether or not it's managed to need another row of results. You're currently treating it as if it returns the next result, returning `null` if it's reach the end of the stream. That's simply not how `DbDataReader` works.

Once you've moved onto the next result, you then need to call `GetString` or the indexer to get the data yourself. For example, your loop should probably be something like:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    string word = reader.GetString(0);
    // Use it
}
```

Now, that will read one result at a time - but it sounds like you actually really care about the *order* in which you read results, as if there's one line followed by a bunch of other related words. That sort of structure should be reflected in your database - you shouldn't just assume that "list of lines in text file == list of rows in database". Aside from anything else, you haven't specified any ordering in your query, so the database is free to return those rows in any order it wants, probably losing your implicit structure. More generally, one row in a table shouldn't depend on "the next row"... if you want relationships between rows, those should be expressed in the data.

You should also use `using` statements for the connection, command and reader.

Comment: Still not working this loop. I add more details of this problem. See above my post

Comment: @General: I don't know what you mean by "above my post", but your question has no edits by you since the original post.

Comment: @General: That still looks nothing like the code I've provided, and won't compile - `reader.Read()` returns `bool`, not `string`, as my answer explains pretty clearly, IMO...

Comment: @General: Please don't just dump significant chunks of code into comments. It's meaningless, and very, very hard to read.

Comment: @General: Where? If it's on the `GetString()` call, then presumably your `Wordlist` field isn't a text field, but that's really a separate problem from the one you've asked about. You need to break a big problem into several small ones, and ask a separate question about each. In this post, we've solved your initial problem of "I don't know how to iterate over all the rows in the result set." Stack Overflow is *not* an interactive debugger - we're not going to write your whole app for you, one issue at a time, in comments. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @General: Well as I say, that's a separate problem, so you should ask about it in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 string str = reader.Read().ToString();
 while (str != null)
 {
```

should be

```
while (reader.Read())
{ 
    string str = (string)reader["Wordlist"]; // or reader[ColIndex]
```

because you have to select the column you want to read and `reader.Read().ToString()` will only return `"True"` or `"False"` instead of the value you want to read.

Comment: Still not working this loop. I add more details of this problem. See above my post........

Answer (score 1):

**What you are doing Wrong:**
You are not using the reader in right method, that's why it is not working as you expected. The [`reader.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) will returns a `Boolean` value.

> It will be false when there is no more rows available
>   to read. else it  will be true.

In your case, you are converting the Boolean value to String by using `reader.Read().ToString();` This will assign either "True" or "False" to `str` so it will not b a `null` at all(as your while condition is `str != null`) hence the while becomes an infinite loop. And also Will throws exception if reader has no rows/null

**Solution:**

You can use the reader in a proper way as like the follows:

```
while (reader.Read())
    { 
      // Enter this loop only when reader has rows
      // Iterate through each row until their is no rows to read.
      // assign value to string variable like the following
      str = reader.GetString(0);          
    }
```

Comment: Still not working this loop. I add more details of this problem. See above my post......

Answer (score 0):

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    string word = reader.GetString(0);
    // Use it
}
```

how to fix this error "Specified cast is not valid"